# Checking if transformation T(p(x)) is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you have a transformation of $P_3$ to $P_3$ defined by, say, $T(p(x)) = p'(x) + p''(x) + p'''(x)$. How would you determine if this is diagonalizable?

Do I sub in a standard basis of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ as $p(x)$ and construct a matrix with each result?

Comment: Yes, you can then see if the resulting matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: So I write each of the 4 p(x) as the columns of matrix A and then check if A is diagonalizable?

Comment: Let the coeff. of T(1) be the first column, the coeff. of T(x) be the second column, etc., and then check if the resulting matrix A is diagonalizable.

Comment: So write the result as a combination of the basis, and then use the coeff to go from the polynomial to a coordinate vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Here is a more explicit
construction.

Let $T:P_3\to P_3$ be the linear map defined by
$$
T(p)=p^\prime+p^{\prime\prime}+p^{\prime\prime\prime}
$$
For $0\leq k\leq 3$ let $e_k\in P_3$ be $e_k(x)=x^k$
and note that $\beta=\{e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis
of $P_3$.

Note that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if the
matrix of $[T]_\beta$ is diagonalizable.

To compute the entries of $[T]_\beta$, note that
\begin{array}{lclclclcl}
T(e_0) & = & \color{red}{0}\ e_0    & + & \color{red}{0}\ e_1       & + & \color{red}{0}\ e_2       & + & \color{red}{0}\ e_3       \\
T(e_1) & = & \color{blue}{1}\ e_0   & + & \color{blue}{0}\ e_1      & + & \color{blue}{0}\ e_2      & + & \color{blue}{0}\ e_3      \\
T(e_2) & = & \color{green}{2}\ e_0  & + & \color{green}{2}\ e_1     & + & \color{green}{0}\ e_2     & + & \color{green}{0}\ e_3     \\
T(e_3) & = & \color{purple}{6}\ e_0 & + & \color{purple}{6}\ e_1    & + & \color{purple}{3}\ e_2    & + & \color{purple}{0}\ e_3 
\end{array}
(Check these computations yourself!)
This implies
$$
[T]_\beta
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{0}  &   \color{blue}{1} &   \color{green}{2}    &   \color{purple}{6}   \\
\color{red}{0}  &   \color{blue}{0} &   \color{green}{2}    &   \color{purple}{6}   \\
\color{red}{0}  &   \color{blue}{0} &   \color{green}{0}    &   \color{purple}{3}   \\
\color{red}{0}  &   \color{blue}{0} &   \color{green}{0}    &   \color{purple}{0}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you determine if this matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: Can you explain how you got the expression for $T(e_3)$ because for $p=x^3$, $p'=3x^2$ ; $p''=6x$ ; $p'''=6$. So $T(e_3)=6e_0+6e_1+3e_2+0e_3$. I am getting $3e_2$.

Comment: @KumarNilesh Fixed.

Comment: That was already fixed before the rollback. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=a_{0}+ a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2 }+ a_{3} x^{3}$.
Then,

- $p'(x)= a_{1} + 2 a_{2} x + 3 a_{3} x^{2}$
- $p''(x)= 2 a_{2} + 6 a_{3} x$
- $p'''(x)= 6 a_{3}$

So $T(p(x))= p'(x) + p''(x) + p'''(x) \Rightarrow T(p(x)) = a_{1} + 2 a_{2} x + 3 a_{3} x^{2} + 2 a_{2} + 6 a_{3} x + 6 a_{3} \Rightarrow$
 $T(p(x))= p'(x)+ p''(x)+ p'''(x) = (a_{1} + 2 a_{2} + 6 a_{3}) + (2 a_{2} + 6 a_{3}) x + (3 a_{3}) x^{2} $

So without loss or generality you can say that for a vector/ polynomial $\overrightarrow{a} =  \begin{pmatrix} a_{0} \\ a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{3} \end{pmatrix} $ , then we have

$T(p(x)) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 6 \\ 0& 0 & 2 & 6 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_{0} \\ a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{3} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}+ 2 a_{2} + 6 a_{3} \\ 2 a_{2} + 6 a_{3} \\ 3 a_{3} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

where $p(x)=a_{0}+ a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2 }+ a_{3} x^{3} $.  Now you need only prove or disprove that the above matrix is diagonalizable.  Does this help?